# Apache Proxy Server Removing Double Slashes

Tags: apache2, apache2.4, apache2.2, apache-modules

Have configured thumbor on my server as a self hosted CDN. However any URL I pass through it has its double slashes merged and as a result I get an error 400. I am using apache2.4 as a reverse proxy. Here is my virtual host configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/
ServerName images.example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Trying to serve images using thumbor so if I put the link

```
https://images.example.com/unsafe/https://example.com/uploads/media/test.jpg
```

am getting this in thumbor

```
https:/example.com/uploads/media/test.jpg(*.*.*.*)
```

The double slashes have been merged to one which causes an error. How can I escape this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is the `nocanon` option that you can find in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

If you add this option, the original url is preserved.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/ nocanon
```